# Activate the Python 3 environment while trying to run the AVHYAS plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I am trying to use the Advanced Hyperspectral Data Analysis (AVHYAS) plugin for QGIS. I was able to download the plugin and upload the .zip to QGIS successfully, but many of the plugin features won't run because the Python 3 environment is not activated. I found an installation help guide for AVHYAS, which gave the following instructions:

[image: AVHYAS installation instructions]

However, when I ran the OSGeo4W shell as administrator and tried to call `py3_env.bat` I got this error:

[image: my result of trying to call the python 3 environment]

Some additional information that may help -- Here is the website where AVHYAS was downloaded from: https://sites.google.com/view/avhyas-sac-isro/home

About halfway down the web page on the right-hand side of the screen is the Technical Report PDF, which contains the instructions I am trying to follow for installation.

Edit in response to comment: One of the tools I want to use within AVHYAS is an Endmember Extraction, of which there are four options. However, when I try to run any of those four options without running `py3_env.bat` (e.g., I just open QGIS normally and try to run the plugin without doing any additional steps), I get the following Python error message:

```
WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/KLKNO/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\HxTools\HxTools.py", line 2015, in doPPI
  from .doPPI import HxToolsDialog
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users/KLKNO/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\HxTools\doPPI.py", line 395, in 
  WIDGET, BASE = uic.loadUiType(
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\PyQt\uic\__init__.py", line 36, in __loadUiType
  return __PyQtLoadUiType(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.1\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\uic\__init__.py", line 204, in loadUiType
  exec(code_string.getvalue(), ui_globals)
  File "", line 20, in 
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users/KLKNO/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\HxTools\ui\qmatplotlibwidget.py", line 42, in 
  from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg, NavigationToolbar2QT
  File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS33~1.1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg'
```

I am assuming this means I need to do something in regard to Python, I just don't know what that would be.

Comment: I added new information above regarding what happens if I try to use the AVHYAS plugin without doing anything else.